# Is there a standard for context replacement?

Tags: regex, vim, vi

In vi, for line

> aaaj

I run the command:

> .s/a*\|j/x/g

The line turns to

> xj

instead of the expected

> xx

Is this a bug of vi?  sed, gawk, and nawk behave as expected, for example:

```
% echo aaaj | awk '{gsub(/a*|j/,"x");print}'
xx
```

Also, if instead of the command above I run the command

> .s/j\|a*/x/g

("j" and "a*" exchanged), then the line would become "xx" as expected.

Comment: Regex has different flavors, see vi's documentation to learn how regex is implemented there.

Comment: "See documentation" is the answer to almost any question in stackoverflow.  Obviously, if I could find it in a documentation, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: Theoretically, it should replace both `a*` and `j` as DFA will be same for both `a*\|j` and `j\|a*`. Your question is good. As my answer does not answer original problem, I removed it.

Comment: Many people doesn't look for documentation. If you did it, then please specify it in the question, avoiding extra guesses.

Comment: Should everyone who asks any question at stackoverflow.com specify that she/he did it?

Comment: The `a*` subpattern can match an empty string and is thus not an appropriate pattern for an S&R operation. Most probably you do not want to match all empty locations between characters that do not match at least 1 `a`, so, the logical wayout is to use `a\+\|j` pattern.

Comment: I set the a* intentionally in order to learn how '*' is treated for replacement.

Comment: `a*` always matches, "wins", and `j` is never matched. That happens because of the order of precedence, the first branch always wins in Vim regex. If you replace `aaaj jjj` it will turn to `xjx xjxjxj` because the pattern will match each location before a non-matching character. There is one thing that is not clear: I'd expect `aaaj` to turn into `xxjx`, but it is not the case. So, `substitute` moves the index to the next character after a replacement. Looks like a bug. See the [source code comments](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/764b23c8fd3369cb05ae9122abf3ca16fec539d7/src/search.c#L755).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" here is the `a*` subpattern that is the first branch in the alternation *can match an empty string*.

When the engine finds `aaa`, the `a*` alternative branch matches the three `a`s, and `substitute` replaces all of them with `x`. Then, the engine tries to match again at the position *after* the 3 `a`s + 1 (See the [source code comments](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/764b23c8fd3369cb05ae9122abf3ca16fec539d7/src/search.c#L755)).

Note that `a*` always matches, "wins", and `j` is never matched. That happens because of the order of precedence, the first branch always wins in Vim regex. If you replace `aaaj jjj` it will turn to `xjx xjxjxj` because the pattern will match each location before a non-matching character.

**CORRECT PATTERN**

When replacing with a regex, you *usually* do not want to match all empty locations between characters that do not match the pattern, thus, the logical solution is to use a `+` quantifier, the  **`a\+\|j` pattern**.